# Как реализовать добавление к всем ссылкам на странице GET параметра?

Tags: javascript

Как можно добавить к всем ссылкам на странице GET параметр, например, `?template=6`, чтобы ссылки уже открывалась по новому адресу `адрес.сайта?template=6`?

Comment: Учитывать ли ситуацию, когда у ссылки есть ещё какие-то GET-параметры? Если у какой-то ссылки уже стоит другое значение параметра `template` (не 6), с ней как поступать? Используется ли на странице jQuery?

Comment: Нет, учитывать не надо.
Задача вообщем такая: при определенном условии (значение переменной в куках например) при загрузке страницы добавлять ко всем адресам ссылок GET параметр "?template=6" - этим происходит загрузка страницы в необходимом шаблоне.

Comment: куки, может, лучше обрабатывать на сервере? Пришёл человек с кукой – то же самое, что с GET-параметром для выбора темплейта.

Comment: Понимаю, что решение не самое "красивое", но думаю, что сработает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо добавить это всем ссылкам без исключения, то с помощью `jQuery` можно сделать это так:

```
$("a").attr("href", function(i, origValue){
  return origValue + "?template=6"; 
});
```

Вариант без `jQuery`:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.href = link.href + "?template=6";
}
```

Comment: а без `jQuery`? в вопросе же нет метки jQuery.

Comment: @Grundy, добавил вариант без jQuery.

Comment: что будет со ссылками, изначально содержащими какие-то GET-параметры? Что будет, если у какой-то ссылки уже был именно параметр `template` установлен?

Comment: @Sergiks, изначально в вопросе сказано, что необходимо добавить всем ссылкам `?template=6`, поэтому другие условия не учитываются.